# How to request https in akka stream

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

This is my code

```
val connectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]] = Http().outgoingConnectionHttps(host = "https://www.google.co.th/?gws_rd=ssl")
 val result = Source.single(HttpRequest(uri = url, method = HttpMethods.GET))
  .via(connectionFlow)
  .runWith(Sink.headOption)
```

and I get error

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.stream.scaladsl.TLS$.apply$default$4()Lakka/stream/TLSClosing
```

How to fix it

Comment: Looks like you have problem in your dependencies. Could you add SBT build config to the question ?

Comment: but I can request with http, I use OutgoingConnection()

Comment: finally, I fixed it (delete some dependencies). Thank you